# MySQL backslash apostrophe

Tags: mysql

I'm having a MySQL issue.

I'm trying to select all rows in a table that start with a backslash and an apostrophe:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like '\\\'%'
```

But this is not working. An example of what I'm trying to select: `\'S-GRAVENDEEL`

How do I do this?

Thanks

p.s.
Yes, this was the result of a faulty import, I know, but now I need to fix it :-)

Comment: Seems like there is nothing wrong with the query. Are you sure it starts with a \ and not a space and a slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got a solution.

Basically what I want to do is fix the entries, so I'll show you what the replace looks like:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(naam, '\\''', '''') naamnew FROM school_plaats WHERE naam like '%\\''%'
```

Apparently, I need to escape the apostrophe with an apostrophe and the backslash with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You need more backslashes:

```
select * from table where name like '\\\\\'%'
```

You need one of them to get a single quote into the pattern. Then you need four more to get a single literal backslash down to the `like`. Or you could escape the single quote by doubling it:

```
select * from table where name like '\\\\''%'
```